# Download File using Rest Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, post

i have download a file using rest Web service (GET) Method.its working perfect.
but i want to know ,is there any way to achieve the download functionality using POST METHOD.so that i can pass some input value.
For GET METHOD i pass Query Parameter in the URL.and POST Method i want pass the value in JSON Format.So can You please suggest me ,how can i achieve this things?

```
@GET
@Path("/downloaddocument")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response downloadDocument(@QueryParam("Regno") String Regno) {

           //Code
    }
```

Comment: could you please be more specific in your question? what have you tried? what's the output of your effort?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, how to pass a value in JSON format. Below is an example of using the input of HTML form:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("application/pdf")
@Path("/downloaddocument")
public Response downloadDocument(@FormParam("filename") String filename) {
    // Return your PDF document as a Responce here
}
```

**Update:** To pass input as JSON, you need to use

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces("application/pdf")
@Path("/downloaddocument")
public Response downloadDocument(MyObject jsonObject) {
   String name = jsonObject.getName();
   // Return you PDF document as a response here
}
```

where jsonObject is an object, which models your JSON input

```
public class MyObject  {
    String name;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

assuming your JSON file has the following structure

```
{
    "name" : "myfile.pdf"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...yeah pass input in json format {"regnum":"123"}.